# What does GG mean here?

Tags: translation, vocabulary, word, cantonese, topolect

Saw this FB post about this unfortunate taxi accident in HK:

[image: gg]

However I have never heard the term GG before and was wondering if its supposed to be shorthand for something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

well, it means “**game over**”

[網絡潮語大檢閱　GG、FF 甚麼意思？](https://topick.hket.com/article/1445010/%E7%B6%B2%E7%B5%A1%E6%BD%AE%E8%AA%9E%E5%A4%A7%E6%AA%A2%E9%96%B1%E3%80%80GG%E3%80%81FF%20%E7%94%9A%E9%BA%BC%E6%84%8F%E6%80%9D%EF%BC%9F)

https://evchk.fandom.com/zh/wiki/GG

have fun :)

**Note: GG = "完蛋了" or "Good Game"**

「GG」是指「**Game Over**」，有「**完蛋**」、「**輸了**」、「**玩完**」的意思，起源於台灣論壇「批踢踢實業坊（ppt）」，後來再慢慢傳入香港，目前廣為高登網民使用。

不過「GG」一詞當初其實是解作「**Good Game**」，起源於電競比賽，對戰後一方明顯勝出時，敗方就會打出「GG」，稱讚對方「Good Game」，有風度地表示認輸。不過大眾卻誤會了是解作「Game Over」，漸漸約定俗成解作「完蛋了」，甚至台灣媒體亦廣為採用「GG」一詞。

Comment: Interesting. What does 留名 mean in the link you shared?

Comment: errrr, i’m also 木宰羊 lah 

Comment: LM = leave name?

Comment: @r13, the first provided link, point 5 explained it. just that, i’ve limited experience in reading this term, in the forum that i visited 

Comment: Hope you don't mind that I added the explanations after your post.

Answer (score 8):

After a close match, the players might say "good game" to each other

It can also be used as a mocky, for example,  I beat you 6-0 6-0 in tennis, but you still played a good game

Typing "gg" instead of "good game" started in internet gaming and is now a general internet lingo for either "good game" or "game over" (you only say good game when the game is over)

In the context of the picture you posted, gg means "game over (finished)"

*I play online GO, I would type "gg" if the game was very close*

Answer (score 1):

(Sorry, new user here, would like to answer your [comment](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/52514/what-does-gg-mean-here#comment71371_52515) but not having enough reputation to comment [@shawn-hemelstrand](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/users/31212/shawn-hemelstrand))

留名 or LM literally means “leaving a name”, which has an extended meaning of subscribing to something (think leaving your email address to subscribe to a newsletter). In this case, it means the user subscribe to this post, and would like to follow the incident. Facebook (and many social platforms) used to notify a commenter when new comments are posted by other user, but now it’s just become a way to say “I would like to see what happens next”.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That is useful to know.

Comment: And in recent year 留名 and its variants(刘明、火钳刘明) sound out of date. Now they say 马克(mark)、马住、放个屁股（put one‘ s butt here so that others can notify him by kick his ass when the article has an update）